# Django Models and Serial Ports

Tags: python, django, serial-port

I am playing around with using Django and a few arduinos.  From my models.py I have

```
class Arduino(models.Model):
    ...
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

I am wondering if it is possible for 'address' to have an auto-generated choice-tuple from a script (or if this is even the right approach).

I was having a few arduinos around the house connected to a django server for sensor monitoring.  I can of course put the address in by hand but I am trying to learn more about Django and programming in general.

Simple app with configuration of arduinos done through the admin interface

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Set the choices for the field in the initializer.](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/26/)